# Movie where retired weak cop stumbles on three women kidnapped by two black men?

Tags: identify-this-movie, crime

Warning: this is a graphic movie. Read at your own risk.  Details are below.

Movie was in color

Type of Movie: Live action

Language: English

Approximate Release Date: 2000 to 2015

Country: American

It was a feature length movie that was rented a long time ago or was seen on a cable channel such as AME.

The plot was about a retired policeman or someone who kicked off force for being too weak and cowardly. The character may have been played by Liam Neeson but not sure.  He is a private investigator that stumbles on to an apartment where two white young women in their 20s have been kidnapped and bound and the mouths are taped by two black men.  The women may have been European which implies setting was in Europe but it could have been in North America.

The protagonist shoots the criminals (not sure on this). He walks to the other side of this room where there is a naked  brunette woman who is lying side ways facing a couch. When he turns her around she is in a help sleep/dreaming/high state and she says, "I'll suck it".  This implies she has been physically and mentally broken by the criminals and have become some sort of a sex slave.

Comment: it's Riichard Gere, but I guess he must be flattered )

Comment: I have to ask...  Are there non-color crime dramas still being made in the 2000's?

Answer (score 8):

[Brooklyn's Finest](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1210042/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_33)

Here's the scene

Comment: Note: in case it is not obvious from the question: this video contains partial nudity and as such should be considered NSFW.

Comment: @Nzall Not the violence, though, right?

Comment: @Manuel Violence is generally considered slightly more acceptable, depending on where you live and how violent it is.

Comment: @Nzall Yeah. I guess that is how it works in most places. Although it is something really, really stupid...

Comment: @LeonFreire To be fair, violence is probably more acceptable because it's pretty mainstream: it's shown in the news (war and fighting sports), on mainstream television (crime serials and slapstick comedy) and in children's shows (cartoons from all nations, teenage hero series). Meanwhile, currently sexuality is a lot more hidden on paying cable channels, shady porno sites and seedy clubs, and aside from jokes for adults like "Finger Prin[ts|ce]" is completely unwanted in children's media. It is getting more mainstream, but slowly and group per group.

Comment: @Nzall Yeah. Its just sad that nudity (I'm not talking about explicit sex)., which is so more natural, gets to be so much more obscure in media than violence because someone at some point decided that violence is something ok, while a boob is not.